# Insert blank line after put or %put statement

Tags: sas

I'm wondering, is there a simple way to insert a blank line after `%put` or `put` statement in the log without adding an extra `put` statement?

I use a lot of macros which write information to the log.  The spacing on successive log statements, however, starts to look scrunched:

```
NOTE: [MACRO] Executing: Main()
NOTE: [MACRO] Executing: ImportData()
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] Executing: ExcelOpen(inFile=\\file\path\to\excelFile.xlsx)
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] Opening \\file\path\to\excelFile.xlsx...
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] Succesfully opened \\file\path\to\excelFile.xlsx.
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] EXCELOPEN macro used (Total process time):
              real time            02.30 seconds
NOTE: [MACRO] Executing: ImportMortalityData()
NOTE: [MACRO] Executing: ImportMortalityDay0ToDay7()
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] Executing: EstablishDDELink(fileRef=mort0_7,
dirData=\\file\path\to\, fileName=excelFile.xlsx, sheetName=Mortality (Day0-7), range=R2C1:R500C5)
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] DDE link MORT0_7 established.
NOTE: [AUTOCALL] ESTABLISHDDELINK macro used (Total process time):
              real time            00.27 seconds
```

I could insert an extra blank `%put;` or `put;` statement after each `%put NOTE:` or `put NOTE:` statement.  However, that clutters up the code quite a bit and I want to avoid that.

In other languages, something like `\r\n` would be added to the end of the message, but SAS doesn't seem to have these constructs.  I know there are the hex values `'OD'x` (carriage returns) and `'OA'x` (line feeds).  Yet when I try to use them, they are printed as literals.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a separate %PUT to write a blank line. Note that you can replace the : with - in the NOTE:, WARNING: and ERROR: at beginning of the line if you want to keep the color coding in the SAS log without the clutter of the NOTE: text.

```
%macro xx;
%* write lines to the log ;
%put NOTE: [&sysmacroname] Starting. ;
%put NOTE- [&sysmacroname] Middle Note. ;
%put NOTE- %sysfunc(repeat(%str( ),%length(&sysmacroname)+1)) Middle Note Unlabeled. ;
%put ;
%put NOTE: [&sysmacroname] Ending. ;
%put ;
%mend xx;
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I've always used `%put NO%str(TE-) Just the color.;` to handle plain colored text.  But then you have to fiddle with spacing.  Neat!

Comment: I have seen people use %str() around the ERROR: text to avoid false positives in log searches. I never do that because it is just as easy to limit search for ERROR to those that start in the first column.  `grep '^ERROR.*:' *.log`

Answer (score 2):

For PUT statement, you can do it with a `/`, e.g.:

```
142  data _null_ ;
143    put "hi" / "mom" ;
144  run;

hi
mom
```

But I don't know of a way to do it with %PUT, other than adding a null %PUT statement.

The PUT statement knows about plenty of fancy stuff (/ , @, @@, delimiters, etc etc), mostly because it is for writing to files (in addition to the log).  In comparison, since %PUT only writes to the log, it doesn't have all the options for fancy reporting stuff.